# The side of an equilateral triangle ABC is 4 times square root of 3. The triangle bisectors AM and CN meet at point O. Find vectors AM and CO

Tags: vectors, triangles

I got AM by using the pythagorean theorem but I can't seem to figure out how to find CO

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! *A priori*, AM and AN meet  at A…

Comment: Fixed title, my mistake

Comment: Do you mean their lengths?

Comment: Yes, lengths of vectors AM and CO

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

- $\dfrac{AM}{AB}=\sin\frac\pi 3$,
- In a triangle, the medians meet at the  2/3 of their lengths.